# how to invoke static html pages in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node and express. I have a created smile page html (test.html) (no templates). I am trying to invoke the test.html in using expressjs . I have placed the test.html in the public folder.

If I do localhost:300/test.html I get the page. How do I invoke test.html using app.get() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You one way to do it is by using redirect. Below is the example.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
    res.redirect('/test.html');
});
```